# How do I add custom attribution to the default mapbox-gl attribution control?

Tags: gis, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

attributionControl: true

Does nothing. Where do I need to put the attribution in the mapbox-gl style so that it shows up in the control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those that still wondering about this. Mapbox have made a good workaround for this as described in [Mapbox issue #1485](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1485).

I'm simply copying the solution provided by a collaborator of Mapbox:

```
map.addSource('attribution', {
type: 'geojson',
data: {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: []
},
attribution: 'Your custom attribution'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not yet implemented. It is sorely missing. Would you consider submitting a PR? https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1485

Answer (score 1):

You can also work around with HTML/CSS + Mapbox CSS Styles by including and positioning a `div` inside the map `div` wrapper by using the `mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib` classes ([example](https://cccruzr.github.io/colmigrationmapbox/)):

```
<div id="map">
    <!-- Modify the style: right position so it matches with the mapbox attribution -->
    <div id="attribution" class="mapboxgl-ctrl mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib mapboxgl-ctrl-bottom-right" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 230px;">
        <a href="*">Attribution 1</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
        <a href="*">Attribution 2</a>  &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="*">Attribution n</a> &nbsp;|
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile the feature is available https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#attributioncontrol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

---- 2023 update ----

here is official mapbox document and example

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#attributioncontrol

here is my working code,

[image]